# Vaadin 8 + Tomcat 8.5 + Java 8u312: Internal server error

Tags: java, vaadin, guava, vaadin8, tomcat8.5

For quite long time now - I'm developing Vaadin Web Application. I use Eclipse IDE running on Windows machine. The app is running fine on my Tomcat 8.5 from within Eclipse and on standalone server running on my computer. Since now - I've used Java 8u212.

Now, I wanted to deploy my app to a server running on Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately - the only Java version I could install was 8u312 so I did. Tomcat 7.5 started fine.

After deploying my app's war file - everything was fine until I wanted to open my app in web browser.

It threw me an error:

```
Jan 28, 2022 3:34:44 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:159)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:188)
    at pl.com.msvc.flexmate.event.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:14)
    at pl.com.msvc.flexmate.FlexmateUI.<init>(FlexmateUI.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.server.UIProvider.createInstance(UIProvider.java:44)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:847)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1680)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jan 28, 2022 3:34:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FlexmateUIServlet] in context with path [/flexmate] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:159)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:188)
    at pl.com.msvc.flexmate.event.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:14)
    at pl.com.msvc.flexmate.FlexmateUI.<init>(FlexmateUI.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.vaadin.server.UIProvider.createInstance(UIProvider.java:44)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:847)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1680)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After that - I've tried a lot of options googled over the Internet (including StackOverflow as well). I've even updated the Java version on my PC, recompiled everything etc. It still does work on my PC and not on Raspberry. I've even set-up Tomcat server on Qnap and my other Debian-based machine. Still not working.

Can anyone please point me in some direction?
I can post server logs/configurations if the'll be needed.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Looks like the jar which provides `class com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberRegistry` is missing

Comment: Hah, this was one of the first things I've checked! Unfortunaltely - the file is in flexmate/WEB-INF/lib/guava-31.0.1-jre.jar

Comment: In the meantime, I did some more research - it seems that the problem is strictly Linux-related. I've set-up another Windows server (clean install), installed Java 8u312 and Tomcat 8.5 and everything works fine!

Comment: Okay, finally got it working (more or less...).

Comment: After few more tests - the app was working fine on every windows machine (I mean that the server/container was on windows machine). Exactly the opposite as the linux machines - none of them would work.
What I did was to set up a Ubuntu based VM with desktop environment an installed Eclipse on it. After that - I've tried to debug the problem until I accidentally solved it by changing the EvenBus class used from guava package to GWT package (com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.eventbus.EventBus). Since then - the app is runing fine on both windows and linux machines.

Comment: So probably some incorrectly (un)defined dependency

Comment: uh, it's really pain in the a**...
after making it to work, I've changed the deploy location in Jenkins build settings to my new Tomcat on Linux. First build went smooth. But the second (and next ones) skips a widgetset compilation :(
I'm starting to cry...

Comment: We are in the progress toward vaadin 22